# Made a program in windows trying to compile on linux using WSL and getting a bunch of errors

Tags: c, visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have these files inside a C VS project in Windows 10 64bit:

main.c:

```
#include "exercise.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int res[1000] = { 0 };//result array
    const char* file_path = "22195_26468.txt";
    printf("%d", detect_correlation_anomalies(file_path, res));

    for (int i = 0;i < 1000;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", res[i]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

exercise.h:

```
    int detect_timing_anomalies(const char* file_path, unsigned int *anomalies_ids);

  int detect_behavioral_anomalies(const char* file_path, unsigned int *anomalies_ids);

    int detect_correlation_anomalies(const char* file_path, unsigned int *anomalies_ids);
```

exercise.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "exercise.h"

#define MAXINPUT 101   //line max length.
#define MAXOUTPUT 1000 //max length of *anomalies_ids.

//struct for saving a message details.
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int time;
    unsigned int ecu;
    unsigned int val1;
    unsigned int val2;
} message;

//structs for different types of messages.
message speed, pedals, ABS, tire, temp;

//open file in read mode, return 1 if successful, else 0.
int openFile(FILE **file, const char *file_path)
{
    //try to open the file
    fopen_s(file, file_path, "r");
    if (*file == NULL) //if the file couldn't be open, return 0,else return 1.
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
//put the current msg details in temp struct (parse the msg).
void parseMsg(char str[MAXINPUT])
{
    char *token;
    char *next_token = NULL;
    unsigned int offset;
    token = strtok_s(str, " ", &next_token);
    sscanf_s(token, "%u", &temp.id);
    token = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &next_token);
    sscanf_s(token, "%u", &temp.time);
    token = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &next_token);
    sscanf_s(token, "%x", &temp.ecu);
    token = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &next_token);
    sscanf_s(token, "%u", &temp.val1);
    token = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &next_token);
    sscanf_s(token, "%u", &temp.val2);
}
//copy the current msg details to the proper struct, saving it for comparison
//later.
copyMsgToStruct(message *strct)
{
    strct->id = temp.id;
    strct->time = temp.time;
    strct->ecu = temp.ecu;
    strct->val1 = temp.val1;
    strct->val2 = temp.val2;
}
...
```

It's compiling fine in windows.
I basically just need to make sure my files are compiling properly "under linux".
So I just need to be able to run this program in Linux...simple enough I thought...oh I was mistaken.

which is why I went through the bother of installing WSL in the first place and trying out all (some) of the solutions out there to make it work, but to no avail.

I tried installing WSL using this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

installed Ubuntu.
I have BASH in windows, am able to connect to the linux using ssh inside the WSL in VS.

created a new linux project, tried to put the same files but i get these errors when i try to compile:

```
exercise.c: In function ‘openFile’:
exercise.c:25:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fopen_s’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  fopen_s(file, file_path, "r");
  ^
exercise.c: In function ‘parseMsg’:
exercise.c:36:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strtok_s’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  token = strtok_s(str, " ", &next_token);
          ^
exercise.c:36:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  token = strtok_s(str, " ", &next_token);
        ^
exercise.c:37:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sscanf_s’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  sscanf_s(token, "%u", &temp.id);
  ^
exercise.c:38:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  token = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &next_token);
        ^
exercise.c:40:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  token = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &next_token);
        ^
exercise.c:42:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  token = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &next_token);
        ^
exercise.c:44:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  token = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &next_token);
        ^
exercise.c:35:15: warning: unused variable ‘offset’ [-Wunused-variable]
  unsigned int offset;
               ^
exercise.c: At top level:
exercise.c:49:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 copyMsgToStruct(message *strct)
 ^
exercise.c: In function ‘TimingSpeedometer’:
exercise.c:62:15: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
  if (speed.id != NULL)//first speedometer msg - no problem.
               ^
exercise.c: In function ‘TimingPedals’:
exercise.c:70:16: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
  if (pedals.id != NULL)//first pedals msg - no problem.
                ^
exercise.c: In function ‘TimingABS’:
exercise.c:78:13: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
  if (ABS.id != NULL)//first ABS msg - no problem.
             ^
exercise.c:82:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘copyMsgToStruct’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  copyMsgToStruct(&abs);
                  ^
exercise.c:49:1: note: expected ‘message * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’ but argument is of type ‘__attribute__((const)) int (*)(int)’
 copyMsgToStruct(message *strct)
 ^
exercise.c: In function ‘TimingTires’:
exercise.c:86:14: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
  if (tire.id != NULL)//first tires msg - no problem.
              ^
exercise.c: In function ‘copyMsgToStruct’:
exercise.c:56:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
/tmp/cclahunW.o: In function `openFile':
exercise.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `fopen_s'
/tmp/cclahunW.o: In function `parseMsg':
exercise.c:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `strtok_s'
exercise.c:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `sscanf_s'
exercise.c:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `strtok_s'
exercise.c:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `sscanf_s'
exercise.c:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `strtok_s'
exercise.c:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `sscanf_s'
exercise.c:(.text+0x134): undefined reference to `strtok_s'
exercise.c:(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `sscanf_s'
exercise.c:(.text+0x170): undefined reference to `strtok_s'
exercise.c:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `sscanf_s'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Maybe I didn't put them properly, using this whole WSL is daunting for me, searching for 1 thing on google gives me an overflow of information that I don't know whats what.

I have GCC installed in linux.
I am a complete newbie in linux and have no idea what all the complex terms on the internet means, only some of it.
I tried to just compile these 3 files from bash using this command:

```
gcc -Wall main.c exercise.c -o main
```

but then I get these same errors.
I think that linux (or is it called, "the GCC compiler" rather?) doesn't "know" these general libraries stdio.h, stdlib.h and string.h which causes the problem.

Any idea how to fix this?
I may have missed a few details because it's 2 am and after 2 hours googling on how to make this WSL thing work, I am a little dizzy.

If there's some info that I didn't write, let me know and I'll add in ~10 hours ...
Thank you very much!

Comment: Those `_s` functons are Microsoft extensions. Stick to standard C library functions, for portable code.

Comment: In `if (speed.id != NULL)` etc you are clearly comparing `int` with a `NULL` pointer value, as the compiler said. Did you mean `if (speed.id != 0)`?

Comment: You may use `#ifdef _MSC_VER #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS only for MSVC`. And replace those `_s` functions with standard ones.

Comment: the compiler complained about standard ones like sscanf, strtok, etc being unsecured so I went through the trouble of using _s ones...so i ACTUALLY SHOULD use the non _s ones after all? basically getting portability over security, is that it?

Comment: @Biswapriyo cool, that worked...compiled successfully in gcc. now I just need to learn how to use that MSVC WSL thing properly...Thanks.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes I am going to change that, though NULL === 0 in structs when uninitilized so i though i might use NULL for some reason (used to C# more)

Comment: Yes, MS wants to rule the world and *warns* about standard functions it thinks you should not be using. Before any `#include` directives I place the following 3 lines in MSVC code: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` and `#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE`. Sadly some of their so-called "safer" versions are no safer at all, or there are safe ways to use the standard function anyway. In particular their `scanf_s` family is even trickier to use than the standard functions.

Comment: the list of warnings (and errors) output  by the compiler are relatively simple to fix.  Take one problem at a time to fix, until all the problems are fixed.   Usually start with the first listed problem as C tends to (in some cases) generate a lot of warnings due to side effects of a single problem.

Comment: when writing a header file, always include a 'include' guard.  I.E. the first two lines of the header file should be similar to: `#ifndef EXERCISE_H`  then `#define EXERCISE_H`  and the last line of the header file should be similar to: `#endif // EXERCISE_H`

Comment: regarding the definition of the struct message,  The struct should have a 'tag' name as most debuggers use the 'tag' name to display the fields inside the struct

Comment: rather than trying to do everything with a single command line.  Strongly suggest using 2 commands for the two compile operations and a 3 command for the linking